# Is there any way to stub these type of functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, stub

There is a file **helperFunction.js**, which looks like:

```
module.exports = (arg1, arg2) => {
   \\function body
}
```

Now, in **file.js**, this function can be simply called by:

```
let helperFunction = require('./helperFunction.js');

//some code here

let a=1, b=2;

let val = helperFunction(a,b);

//some code here
```

In order to test **file.js**, I want to stub the **helperFunction**. However, the syntax for sinon.stub looks like:

```
let functionStub = sinon.stub(file, "functionName");
```

And here in my case the fileName itself is the function name. How do I create a stub for **helperFunction** now? Or is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a library like [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) which can be used to override dependencies during testing.

That would mean you would end up with something like this:

```
const helper = sinon.stub();

const moduleToTest = proxyquire('./your-file-name’, {
  './helperFunction': helper,
});
```

Although if you do not want to add a new library, you can always switch to refactoring the `helperFunction.js` file and exporting your function as a named export instead of default export. That will give you an object having the method you need to stub and that would fit in nicely with your current approach